# Relative path problem - one dir up

Tags: c++, winapi, path, relative-path, organization

This is workig:
I have my exe in the same directory as Images folder;

```
Main:
|-Images
  |-cross_ball
    |-frame.bmp
|-game.exe
```

I'm refering to frame.bmp in my game.exe.

This path is workig good: "Images\\cross_ball\\frame.bmp"

This is not working:
Exe is in bin folder. bin folder is in the same folder as Images folder;

```
Main:
|-Images
  |-cross_ball
    |-frame.bmp
|-bin
  |-game.exe
```

This path is not working: "..\\Images\\cross_ball\\frame.bmp"

Comment: `..\Images\cross_ball\frame.bmp` (created using `"..\\Images\\cross_ball\\frame.bmp"`) should work if the current directory is the one that contains the executable, but that's not always the case. You need to determine the directory in which the .exe is located and find `frame.bmp` based on that. Sorry, I don't know how to do that in C++ or Win32

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If "Images\cross_ball\frame.bmp" is working, then your app's current directory isn't the Images directory like you think it is.  It must be one dir up for that to work.  That would also explain why moving the exe to the bin directory fails.

Are you starting your app from a shortcut or in a debugger?  Shortcuts and debuggers specify the app's current directory, which isn't necessarily the same directory the exe is in.

Comment: So what is the best way to refare to my bmp file from exe?

Comment: Get EXE path with `GetModuleFileName (0, path, MAX_PATH)`; remove EXE name with `PathRemoveFileSpec`, append relative path with `PathCombine`.

Comment: MSalters' solution would be the most reliable, or you could simply change the shortcut to use bin as the working directory and then "..\\Images\\cross_ball\\frame.bmp" would work.  In a shortcut, the working directory is the field labeled "Start in".

Answer (score 0):

As an experiment, replace each \ by \\ and test again.

Back slash is generally used for escape sequences like '\n'.

By putting two of them together, the run time ought to change them into one.

**"Images\\cross_ball\\frame.bmp"**

Comment: I have double \ but stackoverflow is making them onlu one.

Comment: Lol, ok. Put 3 backslashes in your message, and it will display as expected.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your logic is fine.  Are you sure your process hasn't changed the current working directory - i.e. Main/bin/ might not be your working directory when you go to make this change in the executable.

Comment: I'm running it but double clicking exe in windows explorer. So working dir is ok.